# How to set the Focus to a License Agreement Checkbox control using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I wanted to set the by default Focus to the "License Agreement" checkbox in the License Agreement Page using NSIS. And then the taborder should work.

Please help me how to set the focus?

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

  !define MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE $(welcometitle)
  !define MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT $(welcometext)

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX ""
  !define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_BOTTOM ""
  !define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_TOP ""
  !define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_BOTTOM_CHECKBOX ""

  !define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE $(licensetitle)
  !define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_SUBTITLE $(licensesubtitle)
  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX_TEXT $(licensecheckboxtext)

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Docs\Modern UI 2\license.txt"

 !define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP $(mydirtoptext)
 !define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE $(mydirtitle)
 !define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE $(mydirsubtitle)

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

  !define MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE $(Finishpagetitle)
  !define MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT $(Finishpagesubtitle)

  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN ""
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT $(FinishonlineReg)

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

 ;--------------------------------
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English" 

; The stuff to install
Section "My TestApp (required)"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows UI guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/win-dialog-box) says:

> For keyboard navigation, tab order should flow in a logical order, generally from left to right, top to bottom.

but if you think you must force then you can do this:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX ""
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW myForceLicenseFocus
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function myForceLicenseFocus
!if ${MUI_SYSVERSION} >= 2.0
    FindWindow $0 "BUTTON" "" $mui.LicensePage
!else
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $hWndParent
    FindWindow $0 "BUTTON" "" $0
!endif
System::Call 'USER32::SetFocus(pr0)'
!define /ifndef WM_CHANGEUISTATE 0x127
System::Call 'USER32::PostMessage(pr0,i${WM_CHANGEUISTATE},p0x30002,p0)' ; This forces the checkbox to display the focus rectangle
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(pr0,p0,i,i,i,i,i0x13)' ; Change tab order
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you once again @Anders. Now able to set the focus to the "License Agreement" checkbox. As you said tab order is working fine without any change from left to right and top to bottom.